# Adjusting the volume with a uislider cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Im trying to add a slider for the settings page in my game, i have looked around but there doesnt seem to be much info.

Anyone help at all?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [**this thread on the Cocos2d forum**](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6524) will help you. It tackles the problem you describe. As a conclusion it says that:

> **It can only be done using MPVolumeView**

[**Read this piece in the Apple Developer documentation**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more about the MPVolumeView.

Comment: ive just managed to get one onto the screen using `UISlider *sliderCtl = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 0, 125, 50)];
  
  [sliderCtl addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  
  sliderCtl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
  sliderCtl.value = 0.5;
  
  [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:sliderCtl];`

Comment: Is there a way you can rotate the slider so its horizontal rather than vertical?

Comment: That's more of a different question, but you could try and rotate: UISlider* slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
 [slider.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.141/2)];
 [self.view addSubview:slider];

Comment: Cheers for your help, if i were to use the uislider would it be similar code to what i use to mute the sound:`if([CDAudioManager sharedManager].mute == TRUE){
  [CDAudioManager sharedManager].mute = FALSE;
 }
 else {
  [CDAudioManager sharedManager].mute = TRUE;
 }
`